# Egress window well - can't drain to weeping tile because I keep hitting concrete

Tags: windows, foundation, drainage, well, egress

I am installing an egress window in the basement of a house built in Colorado in 1965 (maybe those details will help?). I have dug the well ~12" below where the bottom of the new window will be. The next step is to use an auger to drill down below the footing, into the weeping tile, and insert a drain tube to drain the well into the drain system for the house...

I have augered down into the soil and hit concrete about 2' beneath the bottom of my well, up to 3' away from the foundation. The concrete seems to slope away from the house. I was able to dig to 5' beneath the bottom of the well further from the foundation, but I still hit concrete again. How do I handle this drainage situation?

[image: Basic Drawing of what I described above]

[image: My auger attempts]

Comment: I don't think you have to go through all that work for a window well.  How much water do think will get there during a heavy rain - a couple of inches at most?

Comment: By code you’re supposed to tap into your house’s drainage system when you’re digging an egress window well.

Comment: The 2' could the builder being sloppy with the footing pour.  Not sure why there'd be a 5' deep bit—you're sure that's concrete and not just a boulder?  Do you know if there's a location where you *can* access the drain tile (and how do you know it's there for sure?)?

Comment: 1) I do not know for sure that I would be able to hit drain tile anywhere. I was just assuming/hoping there would be some. 2) As of now, I do not know for sure that it's not a boulder 5 feet deep. It doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: @Timmy Beatty - What if your house doesn't have such a drainage system?

Comment: *maybe those details will help?* That you can't use a shovel to dig caliche? Yeah, there's your problem right there. Dig the well out. Cut the hole, add lintel. Core a hole under it into your house, to fit a drain and trap. Having dug the well out completely, you'll see where you have to core *down*, outside, to get past the concrete umbrella. (do that first otherwise your core-out is prob too high to elbow; hope you like digging). SDS Rotary hammer, a 4" core bit and some extensions maybe. Find the drain tile? pfft. You need a concrete saw to trench to your sewer and a wall to hide all that.

Comment: You have to dig *out* past the 'slab' so you can glue the elbow on. Good times. Need a hole 5' cubed.... not holes drilled into dirt with zero access and 3' too short. That's the footing from the previous house? Or w/e weird drain tile it is? *Finish the demo*. "Keep digging" – Father